# C# Class to field datatable to xml deserialize

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

[image]

The xml string I want to deserialize

```
<cls_Yeni_Goc_Tespit_Formu>
    <hastaBilgileri>
      <TC>12430104982</TC>
      <AdSoyad>AYŞE BERİL HARMANLI</AdSoyad>
      <DogumTarihi>20.09.1989</DogumTarihi>
      <Ozellik>Gebe Izlem 27.03.2018 I. Izlem</Ozellik>
      <GocAdres />
      <Gsm>03121235689</Gsm>
    </hastaBilgileri>
    <hastaBilgileri>
      <TC>12433104828</TC>
      <AdSoyad>İPEK HARMANLI</AdSoyad>
      <DogumTarihi>20.09.1989</DogumTarihi>
      <Ozellik />
      <GocAdres />
      <Gsm />
    </hastaBilgileri>
    <hastaBilgileri>
      <TC>12439104600</TC>
      <AdSoyad>AYŞEN HARMANLI</AdSoyad>
      <DogumTarihi>01.12.1959</DogumTarihi>
      <Ozellik />
      <GocAdres />
      <Gsm />
    </hastaBilgileri>
    <hastaBilgileri>
      <TC>12445104472</TC>
      <AdSoyad>MUHİTTİN BEHİÇ HARMANLI</AdSoyad>
      <DogumTarihi>18.02.1958</DogumTarihi>
      <Ozellik />
      <GocAdres />
      <Gsm>03121235689</Gsm>
    </hastaBilgileri>   <mernisAdres> ALACAATLI MAH. 3346 CAD. 35/88/ - ÇANKAYA/ANKARA</mernisAdres>   <gocYeniAdres> Ankara </gocYeniAdres >   <kayitNo>9</kayitNo>   <bilgiVerenKisi>yasin</bilgiVerenKisi> </cls_Yeni_Goc_Tespit_Formu>
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stackoverflow.  Can you [edit] your question to include your code as **text** rather than as a screenshot?  It's policy here not to to use images for this purpose, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500/3744182) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.

Answer (score 1):

Loading data into a `DataTable` is almost always a bad choice, and most tools hate it. It *almost certainly* isn't going to play nicely with `XmlSerializer`. If you create a `public class HastaBilgileri {...}` (with the required `TC`, etc members) and use a `List<HastaBilgileri>`, it should work fine; for example:

```
[XmlRoot("cls_Yeni_Goc_Tespit_Formu")]
public class YeniGocTespitFormu
{
    [XmlElement("hastaBilgileri")]
    public List<HastaBilgileri> Items {get;} = new List<HastaBilgileri>();
    // ... etc
}

public class HastaBilgileri
{
    public string TC {get;set;}
    public string AdSoyad {get;set;}
    // etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever your reason is, you can load your xml to `DataSet`, then get your `DataTable`s:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml)));
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
```